# SourceBuffer in MediaSource is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, media-source

I'm developing a LiveStream in my angular application. Back-end can provide me mp4 files of video. I am trying to develop my own player to request new parts of the video and for that, I want to use MediaSource with SourceBuffer. 
I'm using this tutorial https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1
However, After I created MediaSource and SourceBuffer I cannot call SourceBuffer.appendBuffer method.

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

```
const videoTag = document.getElementById("video");
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
(<HTMLVideoElement>videoTag).src = url;
mediaSource.onsourceopen = () => {
    let videoSourceBuffer: SourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001e"');
        this.http.get('/videoStreaming/res6547', parameters).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(videoSourceBuffer);
          videoSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data.payload); //<== here stuff breaks
        })
      }
```

For me, it looks like MediaSource.addSourceBuffer doesn't create appropriate SourceBuffer object.

```
SourceBuffer {mode: "segments", updating: false, buffered: TimeRanges, timestampOffset: 0, appendWindowStart: 0, …}
appendWindowEnd: Infinity
appendWindowStart: 0
buffered: TimeRanges {length: 0}
mode: "segments"
onabort: null
onerror: null
onupdate: null
onupdateend: null
onupdatestart: null
timestampOffset: 0
updating: false
__proto__: SourceBuffer
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if the value you pass into appendBuffer is not an ArrayBuffer. Depending on what you are getting back in `data.payload` you could try to convert it with something like `new Uint8Array(data.payload)`.

For example using fetch:

```html
const response = await fetch(url);
const rawChunk = await response.arrayBuffer();
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(rawChunk);
```